# SQLite in iPhone:I want to Retrieving 1 row for each date from sqlite

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, sqlite

i only want to know that whether data is available for any specific date or not.If there are more than one data with the same date, i do not want to fetch all the data.I try to use 
LIMIT 0,1 in where clause but it means it will fetch total 1 data for the given date range.
So please tell me the way to fetch data between a date range with 1 data for particular date.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to choose a row if there's more than one for a given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE(
name,
date
);

insert into events values ("foo", "2008-01-01");
insert into events values ("bar", "2008-01-01");
insert into events values ("goo", "2009-01-01");
insert into events values ("gai", "2009-01-01");
select max(name), date from events group by date;
```

Output:

```
foo|2008-01-01
goo|2009-01-01
```

See [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)